# Term for someone who has lost his immediate family

Tags: word-request

I've come across someone trying to write about a man who lost his wife and child to the 2011 Tohoku earthquake and tsunami. Is there any term like "widower" or "orphan" but for describing someone who has lost his wife and children?

(As far as I'm aware, his parents aren't alive.)

Comment: As you just demonstrated, it's easily expressed--but perhaps not as a single word. The best I can come up with is [*bereaved*](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/bereaved).

Comment: @snailplane That should be an answer!

Comment: @JamesK It's been years since I wrote this comment, but I think the reason I left it as a comment rather than an answer is because Andrew Grimm was looking for a single word, and there isn't really a suitable one.  Since there isn't, he left an answer for his own question suggesting that it may be a "semantic gap", and I upvoted that answer rather than leaving my own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In obituaries, the terms "survived" and "survivor" are often used.  I don't know of a single word to express this, but you could say that he is "the family's only survivor" or "the family is survived by only one member."

Answer (score 4):

This may well be a [semantic gap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accidental_gap#Semantic_gaps) - a concept for which there is no word.

Pakistani poet and writer [Fatima Bhutto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatima_Bhutto) wrote in [A Nation's Sorrow: Today, for us young citizens, Pakistan feels like a country empty of dreams](http://scroll.in/article/695554/Today,-for-us-young-citizens,-Pakistan-feels-like-a-country-empty-of-dreams) (17 December, 2014)

> There is no word for a parent who buries a child. No equivalent of
>   widow or orphan in any language that I know, we do not have the
>   language to describe a parent who lays his child into the earth before
>   his time. So with what tongue do we speak of the dead now? It is a
>   sorrow too large to bear.

Comment: Mandarin seems to have a word for the concept, specifically referring to parents who have lost their only child: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shidu_(bereavement)